# How to hide Modal by clicking out of modal body in React Native

Tags: react-native, modal-dialog, overlay

I have written a code to hide modal whenever user click to the 'hide me' text which is in the modal but I also want modal to hide when we click outside the modal. I can use 'TouchableWithoutFeedback' but it doesn't work for me. How can I use 'TouchableWithoutFeedback' or any other solution for this?

```
this.state = {
 showPopupModal: false
}
  hideModal(){
   this.setState({showPopupModal: false});
  }  
showModal(){
  this.setState({showPopupModal: true});
 }  

return(
 <Conatiner>
  <View>
   <TouchableOpacity onPress={() => { showModal(); }}>
     <Text> open modal <Text>
   </TouchableOpacity>
</View>

<Modal visible={this.state.showPopupModal}>
  <View>
    <TouchableOpacity onPress={() => { hideModal(); }}>
      <Text> hide me </Text>
     </TouchableOpacity>
   </View>
 </Modal>
</Container>
);
```

Answer (score 3):

You have to set isVisible and onBackdropPress attributes of Modal,eg:

```
  <Modal isVisible={this.state.showPopupModal} onBackdropPress={() => this.hideModal()} >
    ..
 </Modal>
```

Comment: What component that you use? .. my answer refer on this https://github.com/react-native-community/react-native-modal

Answer (score 1):

You have not assigned props to the Modal, doing

```
<Modal visible={this.state.showPopupModal}>
  <View>
    <TouchableOpacity onPress={() => { hideModal(); }}>
      <Text> hide me </Text>
    </TouchableOpacity>
  </View>
</Modal>
```

Should solve this.

Comment: Yes i have already assigned this, but forgot to mention, its not working for me

Answer (score 0):

This is the only way I could do this without installing any additional libraries!

```
  <Modal
    visible={this.state.modal}
    animationType="fade"
    transparent={true}
    onRequestClose={this.handleClose}>
    <Pressable
      onPress={() => {
        this.handleClose();
      }}
      style={[
        Platform.OS === 'ios' ? styles.iOSBackdrop : styles.androidBackdrop,
        styles.backdrop,
      ]}
    />
    ...
  </Modal>;
```

Add this below styles in to your styles.

```
const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  iOSBackdrop: {
    backgroundColor: '#000000',
    opacity: 0.3,
  },
  androidBackdrop: {
    backgroundColor: '#232f34',
    opacity: 0.32,
  },
  backdrop: {
    position: 'absolute',
    top: 0,
    left: 0,
    right: 0,
    bottom: 0,
  },
});
```

Answer (score -2):

```
this.state = {
  showPopupModal: false
}
hideModal(){
this.setState({showPopupModal: false});
}  
showModal(){
 this.setState({showPopupModal: true});
}  
return(
<Conatiner>
 <View>
  <TouchableOpacity onPress={() => { showModal(); }}>
   <Text> open modal <Text>
 </TouchableOpacity>
</View>
<TouchableWithoutFeedback onPress={() => { hideModal(); }}>
  <Modal visible={this.state.showPopupModal}>
  <TouchableWithoutFeedback onPress={() => { hideModal(); }}>
   <View>
    <TouchableOpacity onPress={() => { hideModal(); }}>
     <Text> hide me </Text>
    </TouchableOpacity>
   </View>
  </TouchableWithoutFeedback>
 </Modal>
</TouchableWithoutFeedback>
</Container>
);
```

this solution is working for me.

Comment: give explanation to your code and write in proper way to understand clearly